# How do I run my docker container after loading it without running docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file.  I can run `docker-compose up` on Windows 10 which builds and then runs my Django web application. I can then successfully browse to `127.0.0.1:7000` and exercise my web application.

My question is, once I exit, how do fire up my image w/o running `docker-compose up` again?

When I type `docker images` I see two images: `python` and `my_web_app`. I've tried

```
docker run --publish 7000:8000 -- detach my_web_app
```

but it exits immediately.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN useradd user
USER user
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
      build: .
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "7000:8000"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `docker run my_web_app`, it exits immediately because the Dockerfile doesn't have a `CMD` in it.

As others have answered, you can run `docker-compose up` to re-run the container.  The `docker-compose.yml` file contains a number of settings that are needed to start the container.  Only the `docker-compose` command reads this file; a plain `docker run` doesn't.

If you want to run this with a plain `docker run` command, you should do a couple of things:

- Remove the `command:` line from the `docker-compose.yml`; add the same `CMD` line to your `Dockerfile`.  This makes the image have a default command that gets run, instead of needing to specify it every time you run the command.
- Remove the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml`; you already `ADD` the application in your `Dockerfile`, so you don't want to overwrite it with random content from your host.

This would leave you with a simpler `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
      build: .
      image: my_web_app  # (override the name Compose picks)
      ports:
        - "7000:8000"
```

Once you have this, you can translate this to a `docker run` command

```sh
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 7000:8000 \   # ports:
  my_web_app       # image:
```

If you had other options (`environment:`, `volumes:`, ...) you would need to translate this into `docker run` options.  If you need to communicate between containers, [Compose creates a `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and you would also need to recreate this.

Comment: After I run docker build . and then run docker images I see <none> as the repo and tag for the image I just built.  How do I name it properly from the Dockerfile?

Comment: Not in the Dockerfile; you need a `docker build -t` option.

Answer (score 5):

In `docker-compose.yml` file, you have written `build: .`, which is using the Dockerfile at path `.`  and creates an image named my_web_app.

You have 2 images because Python was used as a base image in the Dockerfile, so docker pulls that image first. And the other one is created as the resultant image (which contains python inside it).

Now when you run this command:

```
docker run --publish 7000:8000 -- detach my_web_app
```

It creates a container but will exit immediately because it has no command/process to run.

In `docker-compose.yml`, there exists `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` which runs this command inside the container.

Two simple ways to run a new container are:

> - ```
>   docker run --publish 7000:8000 -- detach my_web_app python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
>   ```
>
> which runs the specified command inside the container.
>
> - Or you can use `docker exec -ti my_web_app` and add the command to run after >this.

Answer (score 2):

That's how you run it. `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1):

Run `docker-compose up -d` if you want to leave it running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dockerfile` generates the image, which is then used by `docker-compose` to build and run the service.

If you intend to run the service without running `docker-compose`, you should define how to execute the container in `Dockerfile` itself. Checkout [cmd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

`CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]`

You should probably move the `command` from the docker-compose file to the Dockerfile and build the image again using either `docker-compose` or `docker build`.

Once the image is available, just run using :

`> docker run <image_name> --detach`